# ANSI color code of solarized theme to customize my prompt

Tags: bash, colors, zsh, ansi-escape

I am using [ANSI colors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors) To beautify my prompt.

I am using [solarized color pallet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solarized_(color_scheme)#Colors).

[image]

To get the colors what I am currently doing is using the following function to generate ANSI color codes alongside the colors.

```
function colors() {
  for color in {000..255}; do
    print -P "$color: %F{$color} Foreground %f%K{$color} Background %k"
    # Use `print -P` instead of `echo` if you want to use color.
  done
}
```

Then I am manually comparing them with the solarized color pallet. Then I am taking the ANSI code of that and using in my prompt. For example:

```
prompt='%F{002}[%2~]%f$(git_super_status)%(?.%F{033}√.%F{124}✕%?)%F{033}$ %f'
```

In there any way I can get the ANSI color code of the solarized color pallet more accurately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you already defined the color palette inside your terminal emulator, you could use [ANSI 3/4-bit color codes `\033\[...m`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#3/4_bit) instead of zsh's promt expansion `print -P '%F{...}'`. That way, you will always use the colors from the palette, even when you change the palette. Furthermore, the colors will also work in any other shell and not just zsh.

**Example**

```
PS1=$'\033[31mThis is the same red as in your solarized palette\033[0m'
```

**Print palette with color codes**

```
echo 'use \033[CODEm Text \033[0m to set text color'
for i in {0..7}; do
  for j in "3$i" "9$i"; do
    printf '\033[%sm Code %s ' "$j" "$j"
  done
  printf '\033[0m\n'
done
```

If you don't care about portability and want to use zsh's `%F` syntax, then you can use the codes `%F{1}` to `%F{15}` (which were already printed by your own script but overlooked because there were many more colors than just these).

**Hard-Coded Colors**

As said, above color codes use the palette from you terminal emulator. If you always want the same color regardless of the terminal emulator settings, then you can use 6-digit hex color codes in zsh:

`print -P '%F{#dc322f} This is always the red from the solarized palette'`

[Wikipedia lists the hex color codes of the solarized palette.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solarized_(color_scheme)#Colors)

Comment: I need the color of the solarized color pallet though.

Comment: Since you configured your terminal emulator to use the solarized theme, this also should use the solarized colors. Did you try this? Which colors did you get instead?

Comment: I am actually choosing which color to go in what place. My current prompt looks like `prompt='%F{061}[%2~]%f$(git_super_status)%(?.%F{064}✔.%F{124}✕%?)%F{033}$ %f'`

Comment: Specially `$(git_super_status)` is using multiple colors.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get your two last comments. Did you try the commands from this answer? **Yes/No?** If you tried them and found, that the colors were not in the solarized color palette, then your terminal emulator was configured to use another palette (and not *solarized* as shown in your screenshot). In that case, you can use hex color codes.

Comment: Oh now I understand. You are taking color from the color pallet.